# Language switch not functionning properly

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization

I have this function here in an Angular project. The function seems to work but instead of adding the full '/la/home' (using la as example but it does the same for en-US) to my url, it only adds the 'la'. I have tried using a refreshing method to refresh my page, I have tried without the initial /. I'm full out of ideas.

```
  changerLangue(event: MatRadioChange) {
    const urlLatinus = '/la/home';
    const urlEnglish = '/en-US/home';
    const urlFrancais = '/home';
    const langueSelectionnee = event.value;

    if (langueSelectionnee === this.listeLocales[0].label) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(urlFrancais);
    }
    else if (langueSelectionnee === this.listeLocales[1].label) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(urlEnglish);
    }
    else if (langueSelectionnee === this.listeLocales[2].label) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(urlLatinus);
    }
  }
```

Comment: How are your routes set up? Are you accounting for the language prefix there?